# How to Find Minimum value from *.txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, min

I have `*.txt` file, which contains data like this:

```
...
30 5.882973099631601
31 6.035463584639685
32 6.184276444600495
33 6.3336851616329435
34 6.492617147379082
35 6.683538372963013
36 6.841228384748939
37 6.999432758805214
...
```

Now I would like to find the minimum value (second column), but I'd like to display it with value from the first column. So in that case I'd like to print this row, as a minimum function and it suppose to look like this:

```
30 5.882973099631601
```

I've been trying to do this with that code, but I'm stuck.

```
 with open('measurements.txt', 'a') as j:
        j.write(str(r))
        j.write(" ")
        j.write(line[24:])
        j.write('\n')
        j.close()
```

Comment: Why are you using write? Do you want to "print" in the console?

Comment: No, I know this code is tricky and in some point not so wise, but I have many iterations so I have thought I can write one whole iteration to a .txt file, and then from this file I will write minimum value to another one.

Comment: That's fine. Can you successfully get the desired row from the source text file?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm stuck with that part. Using 'min' seems not to work in that case. Do you have any idea what to do? Keep in mind that I want to find the minimum value on the second column, but also save this value with attached to it value from column one.

Comment: I can write a snippet for that.

Comment: Great :) I hope I have explained you everything, and that the problem is clearly stated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184624/discussion-between-nitin-pawar-and-hiddenguy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

# preparing data - converting to array
rows = []
with open('sample.txt', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:  # each row is a list
        rows.append(row)

# lambda function to filter min considering the second column
minimus = min(rows, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))

# done
print(minimus)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, but unfortunately it has found wrong value. I've got `['54', '10.010083232292704']` from your function, but I have supposed to get this one `30 5.8826304241360745`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the row with minimum value:

```
min_row = ''  
min_val = 1000000                   # Considering this value to be the highest
'''
Loop for reading rows in source file
'''
a, b = row.split(' ')
b = float(b)
if b < min_val:
    min_val = b
    min_row = row
'''
End of loop
'''
```

Then, write 'min_row' in the new file.